# Switch logo when Scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm kinda stuck doing this, so I need your help :)

I am currently working on a project in Shopify

and here are the problem on my site:

1. Scroll down a bit, the navigation Menu will appear with its heritage logo [black] with white background. Now open the shop button then scroll it up, the white background of the navigation should remain along with the heritage logo [black] plus the search icon [black]
2. Scroll down a bit, the navigation Menu will appear with its heritage logo [black] with white background. now open the shop button then close it, the heritage logo [black] should remain with the white background plus the search icon [black]

You can see the exact output [HERE](https://jsbin.com/suharu/edit?html,output)

or if you want to see the live website:

[click here](https://campbrand.myshopify.com/password) and the
password is: chough

Please let me know what further information needed, to understand it better.

Thanks in Advance :)

**JAVASCRIPT** & **HTML**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  //jQuery.scrollSpeed(50, 800);
 
  $('#shop-menu-dropdown').on('click', function (e) {
  
    if($('.livery-collection-menu-container').hasClass('hide')) {
      
      $('.sticky-target-menu').addClass('collection-menu-open').css('transition', 'all 0.5s ease-in-out');
      $('.livery-collection-menu-container').slideDown().removeClass('hide');
      $('#logo-img img')
              .css( {'height': '55px', 'position': 'relative', 'top': '10px',} )
              .attr('src','https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/logoblack2.png?16348450756183240677');
      $('.livery-search-button')
              .attr('src','http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/icon-search.png?2506340321008419925');
      
    } else {
      
      $('.sticky-target-menu').removeClass('collection-menu-open').css('transition', 'all 0.5s ease-in-out');
      $('.livery-collection-menu-container').slideUp().addClass('hide');
      $('#logo-img img')
              .css( {'height': '70px', 'position': 'relative', 'top': '10px',} )
              .attr('src','https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/logo.png?15237508448918884431');
      $('.livery-search-button')
              .attr('src','http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/icon-search-light.png?16581710301453831089');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    
  });
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
          // $('#logo-img img').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#logo-img img')
              .css( {'height': '55px', 'position': 'relative', 'top': '10px',} )
              .attr('src','https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/logoblack2.png?16348450756183240677');
          $('.livery-search-button')
              .attr('src','http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/icon-search.png?2506340321008419925');
          
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 1) {
          // $('#logo-img img').fadeIn('fast');
          $('#logo-img img')
              .css( {'height': '70px', 'position': 'relative', 'top': '10px',} )
              .attr('src','https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/logo.png?15237508448918884431');
          $('.livery-search-button')
              .attr('src','http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/icon-search-light.png?16581710301453831089');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
          // $('#logo-img img').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#logo-img2 img')
              
              .attr('src','https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/good_company_logo.png?15237508448918884431');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 1) {
          // $('#logo-img img').fadeIn('fast');
          $('#logo-img2 img')
              
              .attr('src','https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0893/1740/t/2/assets/goodcompanylogo.png?15237508448918884431');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<section id="nav" class="livery-margin-none sticky-target-menu">
    {{ 'changelogo.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
              
              <div class="col-md-12 nopadding-nomargin hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <nav class="fl livery-menu">
                  {% include 'dropdown' %}
                </nav> <!-- /.main -->
              </div>
              
              <div class="container-fluid nopadding-nomargin visible-sm visible-xs" id="cus-mob-bg">
                <div class="col-md-12 nopadding-nomargin">
                  
                  <div class="container">
                  <div class="mobile-menu">
                    
                      <div class="mobile-menu-button">
                        <div class="mobile-currency-switcher hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <a href="#"><span class="money currency-switcher">${{amount}} CAD</span></a>
                        {% include 'custom-currency-picker' %}
                    
                        </div>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="responsive-button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                      </div>
                    
                     <div class="livery-logo menu-center">
                         {% if settings.use_logo %}
                         <a href="/"><img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"/></a>
                         <a href="/"><img src="{{ 'logoblack.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" id="logo_center" class="visible-xs visible-sm"/></a>
                         {% else %}
                         <a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a>
                         {% endif %}
                      </div>
                    
                      {% include 'mobile-menu' %}
                  </div>   
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-12 nopadding-nomargin hide livery-collection-menu-container">
                <nav class="fl livery-collection-menu" style="background:{{settings.livery_sub_menu_color}};">
                    <ul class="horizontal unstyled clearfix">
                      {% for link in linklists.collection-menu.links %}
                      {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}
                      <li>
                        <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{% if link.active %} current{% endif %}">
                          <span>{{ link.title }}</span></a>
                      </li>
                      {% else %}
                      <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{% if link.active %} current{% endif %}">
                        <span>{{ link.title }}</span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                          {% for l in linklists[link.handle].links %}
                          <li><a href="{{ l.url }}"{% if l.active %} class="current"{% endif %}>{{ l.title }}</a></li>
                          {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>   
              {% endif %}
            </section>
```